# AWS sts assumeRole fails for cross account api access on second request onwards

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to access cross-account API in AWS using the assumed role. The roles are configured correctly.
I am able to invoke API for the first and after that till the session duration, I am getting something like the following error. I am not sure how to handle this to make every request success. Please help.

> Error: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/assume-role

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var aws4 = require('aws4');

const REGION = process.env.REGION || 'eu-west-1';
const ASSUME_ROLE_ARN = process.env.ASSUME_ROLE_ARN || '';
const API_ID_PARAMETER = process.env.EXT_API_ID_PARAMETER || '/test/gl/module/dev/testapi';
exports.handler = async(event) => {

console.log('received event')
console.log('ASSUME_ROLE_ARN:' + ASSUME_ROLE_ARN);
console.log('API_ID_PARAMETER:' + EXT_API_ID_PARAMETER);
var sts = new AWS.STS({
        region: REGION
    });

console.log('sts success')
const getCrossAccountCredentials = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
        const params = {
            RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/assume-role',
            RoleSessionName: `be-descriptibe-here-${timestamp}`,
            DurationSeconds: 3600
        };
        console.log('RoleSessionName : ' + params.RoleSessionName)
        sts.assumeRole(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else {
                resolve({
                    accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                    secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                    sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
try {

    const tempdata = await getCrossAccountCredentials();
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempdata));
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.accessKeyId);
    console.log(data.secretAccessKey);
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: data.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: data.secretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: data.sessionToken
    });

    const creds = {
        accessKeyId: data.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: data.secretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: data.sessionToken
    };
    console.log('AWS.SSM start')

    var ssm = new AWS.SSM({
            apiVersion: '2014-11-06',
            region: REGION,
            credentials: creds
        });

    console.log('AWS.SSM end')

    const {
        Parameter
    } = await ssm
        .getParameter({
            Name: EXT_API_ID_PARAMETER
        })
        .promise();
    console.log(Parameter.Value)
    let request = {
        host: `${Parameter.Value}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`,
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://${Parameter.Value}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/test/1`,
        path: '/dev/test/1'
    };
    let signedRequest = aws4.sign(request, creds);
    delete signedRequest.headers['Host'];
    delete signedRequest.headers['Content-Length'];
    const res = await axios(signedRequest);
    console.log('Data:', res.data);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
}

};
```

Comment: Wondering what is the role you set to have permission of sts:AssumeRole? In my approach, I would like to have federated identity as the trusted role identity

Comment: resolved..the issue is with AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: data.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: data.secretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: data.sessionToken
    });..when i removed this it works